What is the meaning of the logo of the Tehran Metro?
This is the logo of the Tehran Metro:

What does it mean?  Is it a stylized letter or sequence of letters?  If so, which ones?

It is simply the end view of a subway car in a guideway, viewed from the tracks. It also shows the platform and may imply that the underground subway is ventilated (otherwise why not join the ends of the lines).


There might also be a bit of play on the Arabic letter Mim here مـ which looks vaguely like a train stopped at a platform and which begins the Persian word for metro: مترو

Here's an example of  the letter overlaid on the design.

I'm not sure enough of this to add it as an answer TBH.  I don't know if a Persian speaker would see it this way or associate it with the letter Mim. The similarity could be entirely coincidental.

@Rob, "convey an idea in all languages" is only a goal of a very small subset of logos.  Most logos have a specific target audience.

@mark, Half the population uses a language different from Persian, sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Iran#Languages_and_ethnic_groups and https://brill.com/display/book/edcoll/9789004217652/B9789004217652_005.xml and there is also tourism.

According to the Brill source, Persian is the only official or national language.

Keep in mind that the purpose of a logo is not to communicate, it is to identify. A logo does not need to “mean” anything. It does not need to tell a story or even convey what a business does for a living. In fact, most newly designed logos mean nothing at all. A logo needs to be legible and recognizable, and hopefully, easy to remember. A logo is like an empty bowl that will be filled with meaning with passage of time.
